# Resource "/projectnamehere/.settings' already exists in Eclipse

Tags: codenameone

I downloaded the newest version of Eclipse on an M1 Macbook Pro.

I downloaded the plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace. It's version 6.0

I made a new project, and when I get to the "finish" screen, I get this error:

[image]

Then, if I click finish *again* I get this error, which is the error that keeps showing up no matter how many times I click finish:

[image]

Some stuff ends up actually getting built in the project:

[image]

My professor doesn't know how to fix it, and there's nothing on Google. How can I make this work normally like it's supposed to? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is no longer supported for newer versions of Eclipse as we [migrated to maven](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/migrating-your-project-to-maven.html) a while back.

You have two options

- Use an old Intel version of Eclipse that predated the change to work with a legacy project.
- Migrate the project to a Maven project which will work with all IDEs and doesn't use the plugin at all.